# Bounds on Fourier coefficients for $GL(3)$

Tags: automorphic-forms

I am referring for instance to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/324325/asymptotics-for-fourier-coefficients-of-gl3-maass-forms?newreg=e0382b2a5d6042f6a8d15a7e37ceb348) about coefficients of automorphic forms on $GL(3)$. I know that the Ramanujan on average bound is known and gives
$$\sum_{n^2 m < x} |\lambda(n,m)|^2 \ll x^{1+\varepsilon}.$$

Is there anything known (in terms of upper bounds, with explicit dependence in the fixed $m$ or $n$) about the partial sums (except trivially bounding by the above) :
$$\sum_{n^2< x} |\lambda(n,m)|^2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad \sum_{m < x} |\lambda(n,m)|^2 ?$$

Answer (score 2):

On the Ramanujan conjecture $\lambda(m,n) \ll 1$. As there is no cancellation in the second sum, essentially (upto $x^\epsilon$) the best upper bound which one may expect for that is $x^{1+\epsilon}$.

For the first sum for the same reason the best possible bound would be $x^{1/2+\epsilon}$. To prove that note that $\lambda(n,m)=\overline{\lambda(m,n)}$. So 
$$\sum_{n^2<x}|\lambda(n,m)|^2=\sum_{n<\sqrt{x}}|\lambda(m,n)|^2\ll x^{1/2+\epsilon},$$
using the bound from the second sum.

Comment: But how do you get the bound on the second sum? (for now it seems a bit circular)

Comment: I thought that $n$ in the second sum is fixed, say $n_0$. Then the second sum is bounded by $\sum_{n^2m<n_0^2x} |\lambda(n,m)|^2\ll_{n_0} x^{1+\epsilon}$ from the first estimate in your question.

Comment: But this is wasteful since we have a rough $n^2$ bound on the right then, which is a loss compared to Ramanujan conjecture. Is there any way to do better?

Comment: If you are asking for Ramanujan on average uniformly in $n$, to prove that it will be as hard as proving Ramanujan: Let $n$ be any large prime bigger than $x$ so that $(m,n)=1$ for all $m<x$ so that $$\lambda(n,m)=\lambda(n,1)\lambda(1.m).$$ If we have $$\sum_{m<x} |\lambda(n,m)|^2\ll x^{1+\epsilon}$$ uniformly in $n$ then using the fact that $$\sum_{m<x}|\lambda(1,m)|^2\gg x^{1-\epsilon}$$ we obtain $$\lambda(n,1)\ll x^\epsilon < n^\epsilon.,$$ i.e. Ramanujan.